# CycleGan only producing black images

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to follow a Cyclegan tutorial here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LktBHGCNfw. It also has the Github to his code. At first I thought I had a typo, but then I tried copying and pasting his code and still the results are only black images. Is anybody else able to copy the code and get actual images?

Generator model

```
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, down=True, use_act=True, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, padding_mode="reflect", **kwargs)
            if down
            else nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, **kwargs),
            nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True) if use_act else nn.Identity()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)

class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.block = nn.Sequential(
            ConvBlock(channels, channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            ConvBlock(channels, channels, use_act=False, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return x + self.block(x)

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_channels, num_features = 64, num_residuals=9):
        super().__init__()
        self.initial = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(img_channels, num_features, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=3, padding_mode="reflect"),
            nn.InstanceNorm2d(num_features),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )
        self.down_blocks = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                ConvBlock(num_features, num_features*2, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
                ConvBlock(num_features*2, num_features*4, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            ]
        )
        self.res_blocks = nn.Sequential(
            *[ResidualBlock(num_features*4) for _ in range(num_residuals)]
        )
        self.up_blocks = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                ConvBlock(num_features*4, num_features*2, down=False, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),
                ConvBlock(num_features*2, num_features*1, down=False, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),
            ]
        )

        self.last = nn.Conv2d(num_features*1, img_channels, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=3, padding_mode="reflect")

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.initial(x)
        for layer in self.down_blocks:
            x = layer(x)
        x = self.res_blocks(x)
        for layer in self.up_blocks:
            x = layer(x)
        return torch.tanh(self.last(x))
```

Discriminator Model

```
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, 4, stride, 1, bias=True, padding_mode="reflect"),
            nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, features=[64, 128, 256, 512]):
        super().__init__()
        self.initial = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels,
                features[0],
                kernel_size=4,
                stride=2,
                padding=1,
                padding_mode="reflect",
            ),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        )

        layers = []
        in_channels = features[0]
        for feature in features[1:]:
            layers.append(Block(in_channels, feature, stride=1 if feature==features[-1] else 2))
            in_channels = feature
        layers.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 1, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=1, padding_mode="reflect"))
        self.model = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.initial(x)
        return torch.sigmoid(self.model(x))
```

Train:

```
def train_fn(disc_H, disc_Z, gen_Z, gen_H, loader, opt_disc, opt_gen, l1, mse, d_scaler, g_scaler):
    H_reals = 0
    H_fakes = 0
    loop = tqdm(loader, leave=True)

    for idx, (zebra, horse) in enumerate(loop):
        zebra = zebra.to(config.DEVICE)
        horse = horse.to(config.DEVICE)

        # Train Discriminators H and Z
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            fake_horse = gen_H(zebra)
            D_H_real = disc_H(horse)
            D_H_fake = disc_H(fake_horse.detach())
            H_reals += D_H_real.mean().item()
            H_fakes += D_H_fake.mean().item()
            D_H_real_loss = mse(D_H_real, torch.ones_like(D_H_real))
            D_H_fake_loss = mse(D_H_fake, torch.zeros_like(D_H_fake))
            D_H_loss = D_H_real_loss + D_H_fake_loss

            fake_zebra = gen_Z(horse)
            D_Z_real = disc_Z(zebra)
            D_Z_fake = disc_Z(fake_zebra.detach())
            D_Z_real_loss = mse(D_Z_real, torch.ones_like(D_Z_real))
            D_Z_fake_loss = mse(D_Z_fake, torch.zeros_like(D_Z_fake))
            D_Z_loss = D_Z_real_loss + D_Z_fake_loss

            # put it togethor
            D_loss = (D_H_loss + D_Z_loss)/2

        opt_disc.zero_grad()
        d_scaler.scale(D_loss).backward()
        d_scaler.step(opt_disc)
        d_scaler.update()

        # Train Generators H and Z
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            # adversarial loss for both generators
            D_H_fake = disc_H(fake_horse)
            D_Z_fake = disc_Z(fake_zebra)
            loss_G_H = mse(D_H_fake, torch.ones_like(D_H_fake))
            loss_G_Z = mse(D_Z_fake, torch.ones_like(D_Z_fake))

            # cycle loss
            cycle_zebra = gen_Z(fake_horse)
            cycle_horse = gen_H(fake_zebra)
            cycle_zebra_loss = l1(zebra, cycle_zebra)
            cycle_horse_loss = l1(horse, cycle_horse)

            # identity loss (remove these for efficiency if you set lambda_identity=0)
            identity_zebra = gen_Z(zebra)
            identity_horse = gen_H(horse)
            identity_zebra_loss = l1(zebra, identity_zebra)
            identity_horse_loss = l1(horse, identity_horse)

            # add all togethor
            G_loss = (
                loss_G_Z
                + loss_G_H
                + cycle_zebra_loss * config.LAMBDA_CYCLE
                + cycle_horse_loss * config.LAMBDA_CYCLE
                + identity_horse_loss * config.LAMBDA_IDENTITY
                + identity_zebra_loss * config.LAMBDA_IDENTITY
            )

        opt_gen.zero_grad()
        g_scaler.scale(G_loss).backward()
        g_scaler.step(opt_gen)
        g_scaler.update()

        if idx % 200 == 0:
            save_image(fake_horse*0.5+0.5, f"saved_images/horse_{idx}.png")
            save_image(fake_zebra*0.5+0.5, f"saved_images/zebra_{idx}.png")

        #loop.set_postfix(H_real=H_reals/(idx+1), H_fake=H_fakes/(idx+1))



def main():
    disc_H = Discriminator(in_channels=3).to(config.DEVICE)
    disc_Z = Discriminator(in_channels=3).to(config.DEVICE)
    gen_Z = Generator(img_channels=3, num_residuals=9).to(config.DEVICE)
    gen_H = Generator(img_channels=3, num_residuals=9).to(config.DEVICE)
    opt_disc = optim.Adam(
        list(disc_H.parameters()) + list(disc_Z.parameters()),
        lr=config.LEARNING_RATE,
        betas=(0.5, 0.999),
    )

    opt_gen = optim.Adam(
        list(gen_Z.parameters()) + list(gen_H.parameters()),
        lr=config.LEARNING_RATE,
        betas=(0.5, 0.999),
    )

    L1 = nn.L1Loss()
    mse = nn.MSELoss()

    if config.LOAD_MODEL:
        load_checkpoint(
            config.CHECKPOINT_GEN_H, gen_H, opt_gen, config.LEARNING_RATE,
        )
        load_checkpoint(
            config.CHECKPOINT_GEN_Z, gen_Z, opt_gen, config.LEARNING_RATE,
        )
        load_checkpoint(
            config.CHECKPOINT_CRITIC_H, disc_H, opt_disc, config.LEARNING_RATE,
        )
        load_checkpoint(
            config.CHECKPOINT_CRITIC_Z, disc_Z, opt_disc, config.LEARNING_RATE,
        )

    dataset = HorseZebraDataset(
        root_horse=config.TRAIN_DIR+"/horses", root_zebra=config.TRAIN_DIR+"/zebras", transform=config.transforms
    )
    #val_dataset = HorseZebraDataset(
       #root_horse="cyclegan_test/horse1", root_zebra="cyclegan_test/zebra1", transform=config.transforms
    #)
    #val_loader = DataLoader(
        #val_dataset,
        #batch_size=1,
        #shuffle=False,
        #pin_memory=True,
    #)
    loader = DataLoader(
        dataset,
        batch_size=config.BATCH_SIZE,
        shuffle=True,
        #num_workers=config.NUM_WORKERS,
        pin_memory=True
    )
    g_scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()
    d_scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()

    for epoch in range(config.NUM_EPOCHS):
        train_fn(disc_H, disc_Z, gen_Z, gen_H, loader, opt_disc, opt_gen, L1, mse, d_scaler, g_scaler)

        if config.SAVE_MODEL:
            save_checkpoint(gen_H, opt_gen, filename=config.CHECKPOINT_GEN_H)
            save_checkpoint(gen_Z, opt_gen, filename=config.CHECKPOINT_GEN_Z)
            save_checkpoint(disc_H, opt_disc, filename=config.CHECKPOINT_CRITIC_H)
            save_checkpoint(disc_Z, opt_disc, filename=config.CHECKPOINT_CRITIC_Z)
```

Comment: I'm currently also implementing a cycle-gan inspired from this video, you can check out my repo [here](https://github.com/theopfr/cycle-gan-pytorch) if that helps. Could you also add the code of your dataloader because the error could also be in there